# Summon command error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I entered this command into a command block

```
summon minecraft:rabbit ~ ~ ~
```

and nothing happened

I'm on Java edition 1.16.5 with WorldEdit

Comment: Is this in the chat or in a command block?

Comment: This is not enough info for us to give an answer. Your command is correct and there are no issues with what we can see so far. If you are still experiencing this issue, please  [edit] your post to provide more details of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

My issue is was that I had the command block set to "always active", change it to "impulse" and it should then work when triggered.

Answer (score 1):

When using ~ ~ ~ inside of a command block, the rabbit will spawn inside of the command block, not on top of it, to fix this, do summon Minecraft:rabbit ~ ~1 ~